# How to call a method that accepts arrays as its parameter on a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static double findAverage(int[]nums)
{
    double total=0;
    double sum =0;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        total+=nums[i];
    }
    sum+=total/nums.length;
    return sum;
}
```

I wrote this code to read the array and return the average of all the numbers in it. I need to write another method which uses the method shown above on a 2D array to display a the averages of each row? I have to return an array,.

Comment: Disclaimer: I tagged this question `java` because the code looks Java-ish to me. It might be something else, though.

Comment: @melpomene That would have been my guess too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example that iterates your 2D array and prints the average using `findAverage` for each row:

```
public void printAverage(int[][] array) {
  for( int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i ) {
    final int[] row = array[i];
    System.out.println( "Row " + (i + 1) + " average: " + findAverage( row ) );
}
```